# Showing div's by URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably a stupid question but unfortunately our programmer at work is sick today, of course my deadline is today... I seriously have no clue.

I have 2 divs: **.translate_EN** and **.translate_NL**

Well the problem is I need to show **.translate_EN** when my URL contains /en/ and show  **.translate_NL** when my URL contains /nl/. It can also be selected by: www.domain.com/en/ and www.domain.com/nl/

You will help me ALOT if you can provide me this script!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a place to have people do work for you or replace a sick programmer. It's a place where people have already tried to solve a problem can come and get professional advice. Do a indexOf on the url and then use $('#divname').show() to show the div if it contains the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will return `'/en/'` if url contains `'/en/'` or `null` if it doesn't.

```
window.location.href.match('/en/')
```

So you can write `if` block and make your `div`'s property `display` `block` or `none`.

E.g.:
Make your `div`s style: `display: none` then on the page write that code inside `<script>` tag:

```
var isEn = window.location.href.match('/en/');

var makeVisible = function(className) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(className).item().style.display = 'block';
}

if (isEn)
    makeVisible('translate_EN');
else
    makeVisible('translate_NL');
```

I don't know all your requirements but that code will help you to understand what you need to do.

If you have a jQuery on your page, then it can be done with that code:

```
$('.translate_' + window.location.href.match(/\/[a-z]{2}\//g).pop().replace(/\//g, '').toUpperCase()).show()
```

Comment: Hi Kuzzmi, Thanks alot really helped me out!